# PHP Preg_replace for all instance of specific text?

Tags: php

I have the following text and want to replace all instace which begin and end with ##, how can i prepare regular expression for preg_replace php.
Example

> We are encountering a problem ##anytext## and will update you soon
>   regarding this problem ##textsomethingelse##

My question how can i replace all instance of ##anytext## with specific text?

Comment: I want to replace text starting ## from and end with ## for some thing.

Comment: str_replace("##name##","Alin Purachu",$str) , this replace only one instance, if i have ##email## and some others, then php str_replace ingore all others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) for this task.

And an example:

```
<?php
$replacements = array(
    'anytext' => 'ANYTEXT',
    'else' => 'ELSE',
);
echo preg_replace_callback(
    '/##(.*?)##/',
    create_function(
        '$matches',
        'global $replacements; return $replacements[ $matches[1] ];'
    ),
    'We are encountering a problem ##anytext## and will update you soon regarding this problem ##else##'
);
```

*Note: This example uses `create_function`, but if you're on PHP >= 5.3 you're better of using a closure.*

Comment: "php str_replace replace only one instance like str_replace("###name##","Alin Purachu",$str)

Answer (score -1):

Wondering why a global flag wont work with simple `preg_replace`. Like this:

```
<?php
$string = 'We are encountering a problem ##anytext## and will update you soon regarding this problem ##textsomethingelse##';

$pattern = '/##anytext##/g';
$replacement = 'with the service';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

This will output:

```
We are encountering a problem with the service and will update you soon regarding this problem ##textsomethingelse##
```